# Is there an MSDN subscrition plan that includes the printed MSDN Magazine?

Tags: msdn

Is there an MSDN subsriction plan that includes the printed version of the MSDN magazine for european (german) customers?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about magazine subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Microsofts [MSDN Subscription Benefits site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/aa718661.aspx):

> Published monthly, MSDN Magazine is available free to subscribers in North America, and for a small postage and handling fee worldwide.

So there you have it.  It is free for North America and you have to pay postage for everywhere else.

Comment: Oh look, it's still true in 2016.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/dd362336.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't a MSDN subscription come with free MSDN magazine subscription, delivery fee notwithstanding? I'm residing in Singapore and is subscribed to MSDN via the BizSpark program, and only needs to pay USD$25 for delivery. The magazine itself is free.

Answer (score 1):

(From UK.)

Simple answer: NO.

Occasionally there are offers, a few years back I got an extra 12 months on my magazine subscription --- likely helped by having both MSDN and Magazine from the same reseller.